# Rewrite levels name by rule

Tags: r, string

## I'd like to do a modification in levels names by a rule, but I have a problem when I try to use a Nathan Day solution for my approximate real data set:

```
# your data; intially your df variable was class matrix I changed it
df <- data.frame(x = c("P27C", "P31B", "P12E", "P3E", "P7A", "P7D", "P2A", "P7D",
"P34", "P10C"),
             y = rnorm(10), stringsAsFactors = F)

s<-c("P27CvsP31B","P27CvsP3C","P27CvsP3E","P27CvsP6B","P27CvsP7A","P27CvsP7C",   
"P27DvsP27E","P27DvsP2B","P27DvsP31A","P27DvsP31B","P27DvsP3D","P27DvsP7D",
"P27EvsP2A","P27EvsP2B","P27EvsP2E","P27EvsP2F","P27EvsP2G","P27EvsP34", 
"P7AvsP7H","P7BvsP7D","P7CvsP7G","P7DvsP7E","P7DvsP7F","P7DvsP7G","P7DvsP7H") 

df

df$z <- lapply(df$x, grep, s, value = T)

# gives you the matches but empty slots for a missing value like "P12E"
df

for (r in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (length(df$z[[r]]) == 0) {
        df$z[[r]] <- df$x[[r]]
        }
    else {
        df$z[[r]] <- df$z[[r]]
    }
}
# restores the original name of unmatched values

df$z
```

### Rename but in list format!!!

### and my desired output is:

```
      x           y                                                                 z
1  P27C  2.22354499 "P27CvsP31B, P27CvsP3C, P27CvsP3E, P27CvsP6B, P27CvsP7A, P27CvsP7C"
2  P31B  0.89197064                                            "P27CvsP31B, P27DvsP31B"
3  P12E -0.02313754                                                              "P12E"
4   P3E  0.69916446                                                         "P27CvsP3E"
5   P7A -0.44895512                                               "P27CvsP7A, P7AvsP7H"
6   P7D  1.77619979       "P27DvsP7D, P7BvsP7D, P7DvsP7E, P7DvsP7F, P7DvsP7G, P7DvsP7H"
7   P2A -0.18261732                                                         "P27EvsP2A"
8   P7D  0.12025524       "P27DvsP7D, P7BvsP7D, P7DvsP7E, P7DvsP7F, P7DvsP7G, P7DvsP7H"
9   P34 -0.13434265                                                         "P27EvsP34"
10 P10C  0.19971201                                                              "P10C"
```

## This is possible?

## Thanks

Comment: what is your ideal output?

Comment: My new data frame in x, I don't have P12A but P12AvsP12B for exemple

Comment: what would happen to "P12E", if it's not included in selection?

Comment: My ideia is if the name don't exist in selection vetor, I will don't change it and in P12E case this level don't change our name

Comment: Please unlearn using `cbind`. That `df` was NOT a dataframe and you would not be able to access with "$" operator. And the first column was not a factor with levels. Read `?cbind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your data; intially your df variable was class matrix I changed it
df <- data.frame(x = c("P12A", "P12B", "P12E", "P7G", "P7H"),
             y = rnorm(5), stringsAsFactors = F)
s <- c("P12AvsP12B","P7GvsP7H")
df

df$z <- lapply(df$x, grep, s, value = T)
# gives you the matches but empty slots for a missing value like "P12E"
df

for (r in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (length(df$z[[r]]) == 0) {
        df$z[[r]] <- df$x[[r]]
        }
    else {
        df$z[[r]] <- df$z[[r]]
    }
}
# restores the original name of unmatched values
df
# a lotta clunky, i'm sure someone could fix that for() loop, but it works
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan Day